# FullCalendar.io extend event object from JSON events

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I've been using an older version of fullcalendar and am having trouble recreating my calendars in the current version of fullCalendar.

I have seen the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) and understand the extendedProp created in the event object, but I'm having trouble recreating this action from a JSON result of events.

**Old fullCalendar v3.9**

```
function DoCalendar() {

    var URX = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var URL = AppUrl + "JSON/GetCalendar/" + URX;

    $('#Calendar').fullCalendar("destroy");
    $('#Calendar').fullCalendar("render");

    $('#Calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'basicWeek,month'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        //defaultDate:
        height: 'auto',
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        allDay: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        displayEventTime: false,
        navLinks: false,
        eventLimit: false,
        events: { url: URL },
        eventColor: 'yellow',
        eventTextColor: 'black',
        eventRender: function (event, element) {

            element.find('.fc-title').html(event.title);

            event.eventColor = event.color;

            $(element).popover({
                title: event.start,
                content: event.popover,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'auto',
                html: true,
                container: 'body'
            });
        }
    })
```

**New fullCalendar v5**

```
function TestCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
    var teamId = document.getElementById('teamId').innerText;
    var eventsURL = "/api/Calendar/GetTeamCalendar?id=" + teamId;
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: {
            url: eventsURL,
            error: function () {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        },
        eventColor: 'yellow',
        eventTextColor: 'black',
        eventClick: function (info) {
            alert('Event: ' + info.event.extendedProp);
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            console.log(event.extendedProp);
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
}
```

**The current JSON result**

```
[{"id":"436969","title":"Practice","start":"2020-10-31T22:29:00","end":"2020-10-31T22:40:00","someField":"the field"},
{"id":"955138","title":"Practice","start":"2020-10-31T03:15:00","end":"2020-10-31T04:15:00","someField":"the field"},
{"id":"985289","title":"Practice","start":"2020-11-02T17:37:00","end":"2020-11-02T17:42:00","someField":"the field"]
```

```
eventClick: function (info) {
            alert('Event: ' + info.event.someField);
        }
```

**continues to return undefined**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If, as you say, you understand that custom fields get put into extendedProps when the event is parsed, then why aren't you using it? `info.event.extendedProps.someField`. P.S. There's no such thing as `eventRender` anymore in fullCalendar 5. Check out https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks instead.

Comment: P.P.S. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing - _"Every other non-standard property will be transferred over to the extendedProps hash in the Event Object."_

Comment: @ADyson I guess I *thought* I understood extendedProps, alerts now working. I swapped event render for eventDidMount, I can access color and update, but am not having success with the popover, any advice? 

`eventDidMount: function (info, element) {
event.eventColor = info.event.color;

$(element).popover({
title: info.event.start,
content: info.event.extendedProps["someField"],
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'auto',
html: true,
container: 'body'
 });
`

Comment: Well, from where did you get the idea that eventDidMount provides a second argument to the function? That isn't mentioned in any documentation. Try `info.el` instead of `element`, as the documentation describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation here,
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

You can get those details in object as below. it works for me.

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            events: [{
                "id": "436969", "title": "Practice", "start": "2020-10-31T22:29:00", "end": "2020-10-31T22:40:00", "someField": "the field"
            },
                { "id": "955138", "title": "Practice", "start": "2020-10-31T03:15:00", "end": "2020-10-31T04:15:00", "someField": "the field" },
                { "id": "985289", "title": "Practice", "start": "2020-11-02T17:37:00", "end": "2020-11-02T17:42:00", "someField": "the field" }],

            eventColor: 'yellow',
            eventTextColor: 'black',
            eventClick: function (info) {                
                alert('Event: ' + info.event.extendedProps["someField"]);
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                console.log(event.extendedProp);
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```